# Unable to update app : Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, deployment, java-8

Trying to deploy my first Google App Engine application, I get the following error message

[image: ERROR]

But trying to change the JRE, I still get the same message.

[image]

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I think you need JDK to compile, not JRE

Comment: @IgorArtamonov It does not work neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the JDK compliance setting to Java 1.7, see the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I got this error, except I was trying to deploy a Java 8 project to GAE.  Solution was to add

```
<runtime>java8</runtime>
```

to appengine-web.xml as mentioned here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8